# How to update a Python dictionary based on another dictionary

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries in Python:

```
dic_1 = {"a": {"a": "a", "b": "b"},
         "b": "b"}
dic_2 = {"a": {"a": "b", "c": "b"},
         "b": "c" }
```

And I would like to update dic_1 with the information in dic_2 to get:

```
dic_3 = {"a": {"a": "b", "b": "b", "c": "b"},
         "b": "c"}
```

Attempted solution:

```
{**dic_1, **dic_2}
```

Gives {'a': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'b'}, 'b': 'c'} which is not really what i want as it does not keep the information in dic_1 about {"a": {"b": "b"}}.

Comment: what happens the "a": "a" ?

Comment: You are not asking to *update* anything; you are asking how to create a *new* dictionary out information from existing ones.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: you don't want to keep a:{"a":"a"} in the solution?

Comment: What happens if the value if dic1 is `{"a": {"a": "a", "b": "b"}, "b": {"a" : "b" }}`?

Comment: {"a": {"a"}} should get replaced with {"a": "b"} as the key is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic_3 = {k:(v.copy() if type(v)==dict else v) for (k,v) in dic_1.items()}
for k,v in dic_2.items():
    if k in dic_3 and type(v)==dict and type(dic_3[k]) == dict:
        for k1,v1 in v.items():
            dic_3[k][k1] = v1
    else:
        dic_3[k] = v
```

Comment: Thanks this will work :) I hoped there would be a standard way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for type while updating

```
for key in dic_1:
    d = dic_1[key]
    print key
    for k in dic_2[key]:
        if type(dic_2[key])==dict:
            dic_1[key][k] = dic_2[key][k]
        else :
            dic_1[key] = dic_2[key]
print(dic_1)
```

Comment: Thanks this will work :) I hoped there would be a standard way of doing this